# Tensorflor optimizer operation not found in get_operations

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, graph, neural-network

When I define a class like so

```
class SimpleGraphCreator:
    """
    Some simple graph object...
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph_obj = tf.Graph()

        with self.graph_obj.as_default() as g_def:
            x_input_fun = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='input')
            y_output_fun = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name='output')
            w_weights_fun = tf.get_variable('weight_set', dtype=tf.float32, shape=(5,5))
            output = tf.matmul(x_input_fun, w_weights_fun, name='pred')
            loss = tf.subtract(output, y_output_fun, name='loss')
            self.opti = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(loss, name='opti')
            g_def.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAIN_OP, self.opti)
            # self.saver = tf.train.Saver()

        self.graph_obj = g_def
```

When I want to access the Optimizer node of this graph, I would like to do this using

```
some_graph = SimpleGraphCreater()
some_graph.graph_obj.get_operation_by_name('opti')
```

However, this name cannot be found in the operations list... 
(looking at `some_graph.graph_obj.get_operations()`)

Only when I specially say in the graph that this optimizer should be added to the `tf.GraphKeys.TRAIN_OP` collection, am I able to get it back. Is there a more easy way?

One constraint that I have though is that I can only pass graph objects... so no individual graph operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer) is not an op, but a class that encapsulates the optimization logic. And the `name` argument defines the *scope* of internal variables and ops used by the optimizer.

What you actually want is to give the name to [`minimize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#minimize) op:

```
optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train_op')

...

some_graph.graph_obj.get_operation_by_name('train_op')
```

Comment: Yes thank you... damn... I just figured it out... Im a bit too tired atm :)